# iOS Safari shrinking text in span for hanging indent paragraph

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to make paragraphs with hanging indents for custom text.

The css and html is:

```css
/* HANGING INDENT */
p{padding-left:6em;text-indent:-6em;}
/* INLINE-BLOCK SPAN SO MAIN TEXT STARTS AT 6EM */
p>span:first-child{display:inline-block;width:6em;text-indent:0em;text-align:left;}
```

```html
<p><span>Hanging</span>Other text on line. This is filler text to force a second line. This is filler text to force a second line. This is filler text to force a second line.</p>
```

All is alright on IE, Chrome and the Samsung browser, but iOS (9.0.2) Safari shrinks the hanging text.

If the css *span display:inline-block* is removed, the text returns to normal size, but the span reverts to inline, so the *width:6em* is ignored, leaving the rest of the text to butt up against the hanging text.

If the css *p text-indent:-6em* is removed, the hanging text returns to normal size, but it no longer hangs!

**Anyone know how I can get this to work**, while keeping it simple? That is, no browser-specific shims or js.

Originally, tried it as:

```css
/* INDENT PARAGRAPH */
p{position:relative;margin-left:6em;}
/* OUTDENT SPAN */
p>span:first-child{position:absolute;left:-6em;}
```

```html
<p><span>Hanging</span>Other text on line. This is filler text to force a second line. This is filler text to force a second line. This is filler text to force a second line.</p>
```

However, iOS not only shrunk the text, but also raised it up like super, and no vertical-align setting could change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution while trying to solve why Safari on iOS 9.0.2 would oversize all text inside plain p tags, while leaving all other text inside other tags at their correct size. That would make pages look very strange -- with headings smaller than the text -- though I suspect it was to make them more readable.

Now, while I said I didn't want browser sniffing, I did have some global css to make iOS Safari shrink pages to 75% for portrait so that there was at least some text on each line:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:320px){body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:75%;}}
```

The solution to both my issues was to add another line making any screen wider than 320px (as in landscape) use 100% (note that 'none' did not work):

```css
@media screen and (min-width:321px){body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;}}
```

NOTE: This works for both the variations of indenting:
a) Uses padding and text-indent.
b) Uses position.

Personally, I prefer the position variant, as it is cleaner. The text-indent css is inherited by all children, so one has to be careful to put text-indent:0; in the css for child elements, which is just messy.